# Clicking on input box moves a div

Tags: android, html, eclipse, cordova

I am building an android app using phonegap.The problem is that when i click on input box the top div moves to the right a little bit.

HTML:

```
<div id="top">

<img src="icon-menu.svg" width="40" height="41"
onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='icon-menux.png' ; this.height='35' ;" class="show       a">
<a href="index.html">
<img src="home.png" width="50" height="41" id="home" >
</a>
</div>
<input id="filter" placeholder="Enter game title" type="text"/>
```

CSS:

```
#filter{width:100%;
height:35px;
font-size:20px;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
color:#FF3300;
text-align:center;
z-index:20;
margin-top:70px;
positon:absolute;

}

#top{background-color:#434343;
border-bottom:5PX SOLID #888888;
height:50px;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
z-index:50;
display:block;
float:left;
}
```

Update:I found out the source of the problem.It does not happen when I remove this code

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=0">
```

But the problem is that when I remove this tag the top div moves up when I scroll which should not happen since I already specified z index and position fixed.

I am unable to post image since i dont have enough reputation.Srry

Comment: Is it because the height of your menu image is changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem which someone was kind enough to answer, I think the same might apply to you!

That is because ChromeView adds a border to a focused element and it sounds like it's pushing everything else around.

Add this to the top of your css file to tell the browser to stop highlighting fields when they're focused;

`* { outline: none !important; }`